# How to export full list of outbound clicks in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-data-studio, google-analytics-4

I have Google Analytics 4 with "Outbound click" enhanced measurement enabled.

In my Events tab, I can see that clicks are being tracked and it has a counter for each unique outbound link.

How can I export the full list of outbound links (with total clicks aggregated by the URL)?

[image: screenshot of outbound param for clicked links]

[image: screenshot of URL param for clicked links]

I would prefer to do this through the GA4 UI, but I'm open to using Google Data Studio... or maybe the API if I really have to.

In Google Data Studio, I connected my Analytics account, but it only gives me the "Event name" as a field. There is no URL field and I can't find any way to aggregate by URL instead of event name.

Comment: The share->Download->CSV may give you what you want. It seems to include more data than what you see on the screen.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it does not give any more detail on the clicked links

Comment: I think you can get the extra parameters available in Data Studio by adding them as custom parameters in GA4. You probably have to wait a while after adding them, then do a refresh of your data source.